# Frequent retrieval of certificates from X509Store

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

What performance impacts could occur by frequently retrieving X509Certificate2 from X509Store?
If there are serious performance impacts what could I do to mitigate them?

Framework: .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impact is small, if you still want to improve performance, you can create a dynamic index. Put it in memory when used frequently.